# How to make "grep" read patterns from a file?

Tags: regex, linux, shell, grep

Suppose there is a large text file and I would like to print only the lines that do not match some patterns. Obviously, I can use `egrep -v 'patter1|pattern2|pattern3`. Now what if all those patterns are in a text file ? What is the best way to make `egrep` read patterns from the file ?

Comment: Note that sometimes you need to escape the `|`... e.g. `grep 'pattern1\|pattern2\|pattern3'`

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
grep -v -f pattern_file
```

Comment: For future reference : remove `-v` and just use `cat myfile |grep -f pattern_file` instead if you want to **keep lines** that match a pattern from the pattern file.

Comment: Huh?  This isn't what the OP asked for.  Also, more efficient to **not** `cat` into `grep` -- just specify `myfile` as an argument to `grep`.

Comment: @lingfish you should have stated that your comment refers just to Basj's comment and not my answer...

Comment: True, apologies.

Answer (score 6):

egrep has an `-f` option which does exactly that: you specify a file, and it reads patterns from that file, one per line.