# Using a text file with string to search for files containing that string in Linux

Tags: string, search, grep

To search in Linux for a file that contains a string, one would usually use:

```
grep "search string" *
```

But what if you instead want to pass a file (such as mySearchString.txt, which obviously would contain the string "search string" - without the double quotes... unless they or single quotes are required?) to grep for it to use to search for that string?

```
grep <mySearchString.txt *
```

Doesn't seem to work...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make "grep" read patterns from a file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027306/how-to-make-grep-read-patterns-from-a-file)

Comment: Or [How to grep with a list of words](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17863301/how-to-grep-with-a-list-of-words)

Answer (score 1):

`man grep`:

> **-f *file***
> **--file=*file***
>
> Obtain patterns from *file*, one per line. If this option is used multiple times or is combined with the `-e` (`--regexp`) option, search for all patterns given. The empty file contains zero patterns, and therefore matches nothing. (`-f` is specified by POSIX.)