# How to grep a pattern from a file

Tags: linux, shell

i want to read a file and grep pattern inside and display it line by line.

```
hi
hi
hello
hey
hello
hi
```

These are my file contents.

```
files="testOne.sh demo.sh test.sh"

for i in $files
do
    while read line
    do
            pat=`grep "hi"`
            echo $pat
    done < $i
done
```

And this is my code .

Can anyone help me out with this

Comment: why do you need to do it line by line? Can't you just `grep` the file directly? Just do `grep "hi" testOne.sh demo.sh test.sh`

Comment: Actually its a log file which i need to read and grep a pattern and print it one by one

Comment: have you tried running the command I have provided you with?

Comment: I already knew that command . But i hav taken those files in a variable and taken in to a forloop as u can see in my code

Comment: Echo is, what grep does anyway. Iterating over multiple files is, what grep does anyway. And doesn't it take multiple files anyway? So what do really try to do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make "grep" read patterns from a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027306/how-to-make-grep-read-patterns-from-a-file)

Comment: @jww I don’t think that’s what OP is trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `grep <pattern> <file>` or `grep -ri <pattern> .` (searches in the whole directory even recursive and doesnt matter if upper/lower case). It will display all lines with your  found. If you just need some specific informations of that line, use some other tools like `awk` to get that particular column.

A for loop for files is just overkill and needs a lot more ressources than needed for succeeding your task.

Answer (score -1):

it is possible to do so , with just one loop, so i changed the your code as :

```
files="testOne.sh demo.sh test.sh"
for i in $files
do
  grep hi "$i"
done
```

Comment: it works without quoting the variable and cat is working fine as well, unless you have not tried it ;-)