# I need a Bash that checks if a specific number, let's say 25454111, matches any of the patterns stored in a text file.can I achieve this?

Tags: bash, grep

Question:
I have a flat file that contains a list of numbers and regular expressions (regex) patterns. I need to write a Bash script that checks if a given number matches any of the regex patterns in the file. How can I accomplish this?

Details:

The flat file is in text format, with each line containing a single regex pattern.
The script should take a number as an argument and compare it against the regex patterns in the file.
If the number matches any of the regex patterns, the script should indicate that a match is found.
If the number does not match any of the regex patterns, the script should indicate that no match is found.
I'm looking for a Bash script that efficiently reads the file, performs the regex matching, and provides the appropriate output.

Thank you!

tried

```
grep -E 523167082 /etc/freeswitch/dialplan/public/oracle.txt
```

returns `523167082` 
but

```
grep -E 25454111 /etc/freeswitch/dialplan/public/oracle.txt
```

returns empty even though in the file there is a line  `254541[1-4]\d`

Comment: please update the question with a sample set of lines from the file (eg, 3-5 lines); making sure to provide lines that match the search and lines that don't match the search

Comment: if searching for `123`, should it match on `abc123def`? or should it be an exact 'word' match (ie, it only matches on the complete string `123`)

Comment: @markp-fuso i posted it " even though in the file there is a line 254541[1-4]\d" and 25454111  should match to  254541[1-4]\d looking for exact

Comment: does not match, return empty. In reguler regex  '254541[1-4]\d ' and '25454111' is a match

Comment: Duplicate: [How to make "grep" read patterns from a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7027306/4518341)

Comment: @wjandrea thank you for the info as i answered  markp-fuso this answer does not work for me

Comment: @benphone Then have you considered looping over the lines of the file manually?

Answer (score 2):

You're doing this backwards. The first argument to `grep` is the pattern, not the string you're trying to match against the pattern. The string you want to match should be in standard input.

If the patterns are in a file, you can use the `-f pathname` option to get them from there.

```
grep -P -f oracle.txt <<<25454111
```

You also need to use GNU `grep` with the `-P` option to support `\d` escape sequences in regular expressions.

Comment: tried this returns a empty response

Comment: `grep -E` doesn't support `\d`. Use `grep -P` to get PCRE, if you're using GNU grep.

Comment: @BARMER  grep: the -P option only supports a single pattern. if i put only 1 line (254541[1-4]\d) it  still returns empty

Answer (score 1):

Sample pattern file:

```
$ cat oracle.txt
254541[1-4]\d
```

Modifying OP's current command to use `oracle.txt` as the source of the `grep` patterns:

```
$ echo 25454111 | grep -E -f oracle.txt
grep: warning: stray \ before d

$ grep -E -f oracle.txt <<< "25454111"
grep: warning: stray \ before d
```

**NOTES:**

- older `GNU grep` versions (eg, 3.1, 3.7) generate the warning message and returns nothing
- newer `GNU grep` versions (eg, 3.8) masks the warning while returning nothing

`\d` is not a valid escape sequence in `grep/ERE`; let's try `grep/PCRE`:

```
$ echo 25454111 | grep -P -f oracle.txt
25454111

$ grep -P -f oracle.txt <<< "25454111"
25454111
```

**NOTE:** same result is generated for tested `GNU grep` versions (3.1, 3.7, 3.8)

Comment: grep: the -P option only supports a single pattern if i put only 1 line (254541[1-4]\d) it returns empty